# Is there a way to retrieve a GitLab project ID using the project path?

Tags: python, rest, http, gitlab, gitlab-api

I am currently trying to write a Python Script which when given the HTTP path of a Gitlab project (ex. https://gitlab.com/path/to/project.git) I want to retrieve the project ID of the project associated with that URL.

Answer (score 0):

URL encode the path and use it as the project ID:
https://gitlab.com/api/v4/projects/path%2Fto%2Fproject

Note that this uses the UI path to the project, not the git HTTP URL.
Usually the only difference is the ".git", but I don't know whether that's by definition.